# How to access multiple cells from a query result

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, fetch

Using the following php code:

```
$queryfor = "SELECT * FROM entrydata WHERE data_email = '{$email}'";
$resultfor = mysqli_query($connection, $queryfor);
if (!$resultfor){die("Database Failed1!");} 

$rowfor = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultfor);
```

If I use `$rowfor["other_column"]` I receive the data from another column which had the given `{$email}` in its data_email column.

** My problem is I have multiple rows with the same email address in their data_email column.  How do I access the "other_column" for the second and third match to my `{$email}` query. **

I've tried using mysqli_fetch_array and combinations of `$rowfor[x][y]` with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysqli_fetch_array()` returns an array for one record at a time so try iterating using while loop like:

```
while($rowfor = mysqli_fetch_array($resultfor))
{
       echo $rowfor["yourColumnName"]."<br />";
}
```

`mysqli_fetch_array()` will return false when there are no more rows in your resultSet.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
while($rowfor = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultfor))
{
    if($rowfor["other_column"] == ...)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

to access all columns of you query result